# How do I force OSX to use IGMP version 2?

Tags: macos, network

I am connected to an old NETGEAR smart-switch which only supports IGMPv2. It doesnt route multicast traffic to my mac because it joins the group using IGMPv3.

I tried this:

```
sysctl net.inet.igmp.default_version=2
```

but it doesn't work - OSX still sends out IGMPv3 packets (confirmed with wireshark).

Is there a way of forcing IGMPv2?

Im using Yosemite (10.10.2), in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is a beginning of an answer here :

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3328862

Answer (score -1):

This commands should forward to the correct IGMP.

```
 sudo sysctl net.inet.igmp.default_version=2
 sudo sysctl net.inet.igmp.sendra=0
```